# PHP - How to write Emojii in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm generating successfully a PDF file using TCPDF library but i need to write emojii.
For example:

```
"Hello everybody ".
```

With helveticaB font i obtain quesion mark instead of emojii but using other fonts i obtain literally nothing.

```
"Hello everybody "  = "Hello everybody"
```

What i tried without success:

- change unicode from UTF-8 to utf8mb4
- find a font compatible with emojii

Comment: Library Website: https://tcpdf.org